# Characteristic Function of a Double Exponential (Laplace) Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let X have the double exponential (or Laplace) distribution with $\alpha =0$, $\beta = 1$: $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$, $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Show that $\varphi _{X}(u)=\frac{1}{1+u^{2}}$.

We are given a hint to use the result of the previous exercise (Let $\mu_{1},\cdots,\mu_{n}$ be probability measures. Suppose $\lambda_{j}\geq 0$ ($1\leq j \leq n$) and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\lambda_{j}}=1$. Let $\nu = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}\mu_{j}$. Show that $\nu$ is a probability measure too, and that $\hat{\nu}(u)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}\hat{\mu_{j}}(u)$).

I am having trouble seeing how all of this information fits all together, and how the hint is supposed to help me. Am I supposed to break the density up into two densities because of the $|\, |$? And if so, how do I do this?

I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In this question as in [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/551571/15941), your instructor seems to be going out of the way to suggest a cumbersome method of solving a relatively straightforward problem. Here the idea seems to be to show that $X$ has a mixture pdf that is the average of an exponential pdf on $\mathbbR^+$ and an exponential pdf on $\mathbb R^-$ and so the characteristic function is also the average of the characteristic functions. But the characteristic functions are complex conjugates of each other and hence ....

Comment: I'm trying it that way - what I'm having trouble with now is getting rid of the infinities in the integral $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(iu+1)x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(iu-1)x}dx$.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out.