# Showing the expectation of the third moment of a sum = the sum of the expectation of the third moment

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}$ be independent, each with mean 0, and each with finite third moments. Show that $E\left\{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)^{3}\right\} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}E\left\{ X_{i}^{3} \right \}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the approach with characteristic functions, we have to use the fact that $\varphi_{S_n}(t)=\prod_{j=1}^n\varphi_{X_j}(t)$.

here is an other approach: we have, noting by $[n]$ the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$, 
$$\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^3=\sum_{(i,j,k)\in [n]^3}\mathbb E(X_iX_jX_k).$$
The set $[n]^3$ can be divided into the $(i,j,k)$ such that:

1. $i=j=k$;
2. two indexes coincide, but not the third one;
3. all the indexes are different.

The sum of the indexes in 2. is $0$ as the terms are of the form $\mathbb E(X_i^2X_j)$, which is equal by independence to $\mathbb E(X_i^2)\mathbb EX_j=0$, and the same remark applies to 3.

It's actually the phenomenon which will appear when you will compute the third derivative of a product (either there is a factor differentiated three times, or two times an an other factor one time, or three different factors).

Comment: +1. It is not unthinkable that OP is not familiar with notation $\left[n\right]^{3}$

Comment: @drhab Yes, I've added the definition. Thank you.(your approach is good too)

Comment: Do you know how to compute the derivative of a product of $n$ function? // The interest of the notation $[n]$ is that the index of the sum is not too long (it has only a formatting interest).

Comment: Davide, thank you so much for your beautiful solution! I finally was able to wrap my head around it, and it is quite brilliant. I'm sorry I got snippy with you before - I've been trying to figure out this problem for the past couple of days, and I guess I started to panic. Again, I apologize and thank you from the bottom of my heart. One thing, though - in the two cases where some of the indices could be the same, it doesn't matter that it doesn't equal the right-hand side? (Probably a silly question, but better to ask anyway.)

Answer (score 8):

I should choose for induction:
$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)^{3}\right]=E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right)^{3}+3X_{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right)^{2}+3X_{n}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}+X_{n}^{3}\right]$.

By induction:

$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right)^{3}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E\left[X_{i}^{3}\right]$.

Further we have:

$E\left[X_{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right)^{2}\right]=E\left[X_{n}\right]E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right)^{2}\right]=0$
since $E\left[X_{n}\right]=0$

and:

$E\left[X_{n}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right]=E\left[X_{n}^{2}\right]E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right]=0$
since $E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_{i}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E\left[X_{i}\right]=0$.

So our final result is:

$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)^{3}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E\left[X_{i}^{3}\right]+E\left[X_{n}^{3}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\left[X_{i}^{3}\right]$

Answer (score 2):

Ok the idea is that
$$E\{(\sum_{j=1}^n{X_i})^3\} = E\{\sum_{j=1}^n{X_i^3}+...\}$$

where ... contains the cross terms of the expansion of $(\sum_{j=1}^n{X_i})^3$, however all the cross term will be in the form $a_1X_iX_j^2$ or $a_2X_iX_jX_k$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants. Taking expectation, we get $$E\{a_1X_iX_j^2\}=a_1E\{X_i\}E\{X_j^2\}=0$$ by independence, and similarly
$$E\{a_2X_iX_jX_k\}=a_2E\{X_i\}E\{X_j\}E\{X_k\}=0$$
Hence we have 
$$E\{(\sum_{j=1}^n{X_i})^3\} = E\{\sum_{j=1}^n{X_i^3}\} = \sum_{j=1}^nE\{{X_i^3}\}$$ after simplying the expectation of cross terms.

Answer (score 2):

Hint( without characteristic functions):

Expand  $(\sum_{k=1}^n a_i)^3$ and use facts, that $E X_1 X_2^2 = EX_1 \cdot E X_2^2$ and $E X_1 X_2 X_3 = E X_1 \cdot EX_2 \cdot E X_3$for independent random variables